# Mapping Mac CMD key to Ctrl on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, keyboard

I frequently go between a Macbook and a Raspberry Pi and trying to switch between `CMD+C` and `Ctrl+C` is a constant source of frustration.

The Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian and I am guessing there is a way to map the Mac CMD key to be equal to Ctrl.

How do I do this?

Comment: The default Mac mapping in preferences impacts the whole system so from the Mac side I would use https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/ and set the mappings per application (SSH application / VNC being the obvious ones). I've not tried on a Pi but `xev` will display key press codes and `xmodmap` will map the codes to a new function in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I will give those commands a go and see if I can change the mapping 